# How is a callback different from and advantageous to conditional function calls for event handling?

Tags: c, callback, event-handling, function-pointers

I understand that in case of implementing a library where a library programmer doesn't know

1. what different clients want to do after calling a particular library API (e.g. timer APIs)
   or
2. for which purpose they want to call the library API (e.g. a sort library, different methods of comparison available for different type of data),

the programmer provides a parameter in his API for a function pointer which is a good use of callback functions.

I have read [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/callbacks/article.php/c10557/Callback-Functions-Tutorial.htm) about callbacks, but am still a little confused. How is a callback different from a normal function call in case of event handling? As I see them, they are analogous to normal function calls made in a switch statement, like this:

```
switch(eventType) {
    case EventA: handleEventA(); break;
    case EventB: handleEventB(); break;
    ...
}
```

How is "registering callbacks" different from this, and what are the advantages to doing so?

Comment: There's a fundamental difference, when your API is compiled, you don't know what handlers will be called. switch/case structures needs information known at compile time. You wouldn't be able to use switch/case even if you wanted to.

Comment: This is a very well asked question. I have made some minor changes and added an example of what I believe you meant by "normal function calls in a switch case". Can you read it over and confirm that I didn't misunderstand, or edit it if I did?

Comment: @Jeff thanks for your input..but in case of callback registration too,  programmer knows that which event handler is for the which event. And similar things get stored in an array of structures(most common approach) so it means compiler knows the data/function. I don't see here any run time changes with callbacks. That is what my main confusion is. Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw thanx for the editing..it is more meaningful now.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage of using callbacks is that you can call a subroutine defined in higher software level from a lower software level subroutine.

Let's take an example :

1. Library function **fetchData**

   int fetchData(type1 arg1 , type2 arg2, ... , functionPointerType funcPointer)
2. Let's assume **fetchData** gets data from a HTTP server.
3. Now suppose the user of the library wants to handle the data that **fetchData** gets from the HTTP server

4.So user will define a function **handelData** with prototype matching functionPointerType and will pass the pointer to this function to fetchData.

5.So whenever **fetchData**(lower level subroutine) gets content from HTTP server it will pass that data to **handleData**(higher level subroutine)

6.In my higher level subroutine i can handle the data passed from lower level subroutine, say based on content-type or any other attribute associated with that data.

If i were to use **normal function calls made in a switch statement**, then that code would have gone in the fetchData itself, so this doesn't give the user of the library the flexibilty of handling data according to the needs of his application.

The classic example of using callbacks is signal handling in C(Linux)

```
void takeAction(int signo)
{
  printf("Recieved SIGKILL (kill -%d)\nExiting now...\n",signo);
  exit(0);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT,takeAction);
  while(1)
  {
    printf("In Main...\n");
    sleep(2);
  }
}
```

Here application can handle the signal as per the requirements of the application.